# API data into the Highscharts without key and value

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

Please anyone help me to pass the API data into the highcharts, without key and name. I'm trying to do in javascript. How to iterate through it. please find below the API result sample.

```
{      
    [
        "2020-08-05T10:00:00",
        1,
        345,
        45654,
        654
    ],
    [
        "2020-08-05T00:05:00",
        15,
        165.8,
        1,
        18,
    ],
}
```

Comment: You should give us some more info. For starters, which chart do you want to put this values into?

Comment: I want to create a line chart using Highcharts template.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an array of keys inside the series object.
Iside that array, specify the API properties for the `line` type chart.
The chart will iterate through it automatically.
More information on how data should be declared for each series and what essential information is needed, you might always find in series type data documentation.
Also I suggest using some kind of timestamp instead of the string, because that way chart treats the string as a category.

**API:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.keys
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data
**Live demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wkz6hu9q/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But how to push data from javascript. I'm not able to push data using for loop to an array ,how to iterate through it?  and also how to pass data dynamically? Could you please help me.

Comment: I can advise checking the documentation: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-intro
If you won't find the necessary information there, please share more details about your issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63988883/mutiline-charts-dynamically-from-an-api-request

Comment: Please find the above link, i have mentioned clearly my issues..  Thank you for your response. I'm looking forward your reply