# Mutiline charts Dynamically from an API request

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, multiline

I have API response in this pattern and i want to add this data dynamically into the highcharts. I also want to make a seperate array for each column and then pass each each array into Highcharts. Can anyone help me to solve this problem. When i tried to iterate through into the API result, Result would be undefined.

Sample API response:

```
{
 "data": [
  [
  {
    "name": "Time",
    "unit":"Y-m-d"
  },
  {
    "location": "XYZ",
    "name": "ABC",
    "unit": "kmh",
   },
  {
    "location": "A1",
    "name": "xcds",
    "unit": "kmh",

  },
  {
    "location": "A2",
    "name": "efg",
    "unit": "avg",

  },
  {
    "location": "A3",
    "name": "fgf",
    "unit": "avg",

  },
  {
    "location": "A1",
    "name": "klm",
    "unit": "kmh",

  },
  {
    "location": "A5",
    "name": "ABCDE",
    "unit": "kmh",

  }
],
[
  "2020-08-05T10:00:00",
 43.8
 67
 65.2
 56
 6765
],
[
  "2020-08-05T10:05:00",
  2.69924,
  65.8,
  7.
  136,
  11.5,
 19
],
[
  "2020-08-05T10:10:00",
  18.3
  93.6,
  21,
  23,
  26,
  15,
],
[
  "2020-08-05T10:15:00",
  39,
  26,
  24
  89,
  70.48,
  1.10
],
```

],
}

How to pass each index value into array?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first for loop creates array of objects with the name as key and value, next for loop creates an object with name as key and array of values

```
const headers = res.data[0];
const final = [];
const columArr = {};
for (let i = 1; i < res.data.length; i++){
    let obj = {};
    headers.forEach((head, index)=>{
        obj[head.name] = res.data[i][index]
    });
    final.push(obj);
}
for (let j = 1; j < res.data.length; j++){
    headers.forEach((head, index)=>{
        if(columArr[head.name]){
            columArr[head.name].push(res.data[j][index])
        } else {
            columArr[head.name] = [res.data[j][index]]
        }
    });
}
console.dir(final,{depth:null})
console.dir(columArr,{depth:null})
const dataArray = [];
for(let key of Object.keys(columArr)){     
    dataArray.push({
        data:columArr[key].reverse(),
        type: 'line',
        name: key
    });
}
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
              type: 'spline',
              renderTo: "container"
            },
            colors: ['#6e9fc5', '#ffdf51', '#a6ca6d', '#ad46d6', '#f26a2e', '#00adef', '#f4bb90'],
            title: {
              text: ' values'
            },
            subtitle: {
              text: ' Data'
            },
            xAxis: {
              categories: columArr['Time'].reverse() //.reverse() to have the min year on the left 
            },
            plotOptions: {
              series: {
                marker: {
                  enabled: false
                }
              }
            },
            tooltip: {
              valueDecimals: 2,
              pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>'
            },
              series:dataArray
 })
```

Comment: Thank you for help. i have one more queries. how to store the result array into seperate array. soo, that i acn push the data into highcharts

Comment: which result array and which loop first for loop or second for loop

Comment: second for loop.. i want to store the result into separate array.. i mean want 6 arrays with its values.. and want to push that array into highcharts to get a multiline graph

Comment: you can use Object.keys() function to get the keys and then you can access all the arrays inside columnArr object

Comment: var dataArray = [], array_final =[];  dataArray.push(columArr.Time) ; dataArray.push(columArr["ABC"]) ;

Comment: I used the above method to extract data into an array. but when i try to push the array into into Highcharts, values are not passed. I'm doing anything wrong? can you please guide me

Comment: why are you adding everything in dataArray, not sure about the format needed as input to highcharts

Comment: is this the format that you are using                                                                         
 `var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            allowPointSelect: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    },{
    data:[10,20]
    }]
});`

Comment: I want all the time series as X-axis, and values of 5 different arrays should be y_axis with 5 different line graph

Comment: not sure of the timeseries, but
`for(let key of Object.keys(columArr)){
    dataArray.push({data:columArr[key]});
}` doing this will give you array of data just insert it in the highchart

Comment: If do the above code dataArray contains all the arrays. I want separate array for each data set

Comment: Hi Thank You so much it works.. i'm passing as complete array, but i want the time as x-axis. could you please help me with this.

Comment: I added `columArr['Time'].reverse()` in x-axis categories that should work I guess

Answer (score 0):

```
         var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                  type: 'spline',
                  renderTo: "container"
                },
                colors: ['#6e9fc5', '#ffdf51', '#a6ca6d', '#ad46d6', '#f26a2e', '#00adef', '#f4bb90'],
                title: {
                  text: ' values'
                },
                subtitle: {
                  text: ' Data'
                },
                xAxis: {
                  categories: dataArray.reverse() //.reverse() to have the min year on the left 
                },
                plotOptions: {
                  series: {
                    marker: {
                      enabled: false
                    }
                  }
                },
                tooltip: {
                  valueDecimals: 2,
                  pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>'
                },
                  series: [{
                      type: 'line',
                      name: 'ABC',
                      data : array_final.reverse()
                  }, {
                      name: 'XYx',
                      data: array_final1.reverse()
                  }, {
                      name: 'xyz',
                      data: array_final2.reverse()
                  }, {
                      name: 'klm',
                      data: array_final3.reverse()
                  }, {
                      name: 'ddd',
                      data: array_final4.reverse()
                  }, {
                      name: ''ABCD",
                      data: array_final5.reverse()
                  }]
```